# TIMESTAMP from CSV via API

Tags: google-bigquery

Does the API support importing a CSV to a new table when there is a TIMESTAMP field?

If I manually (using the BigQuery web interface) upload a CSV file containing timestamp data, and specify the field to be a TIMESTAMP via the schema, it works just fine. The data is loaded. The timestamp data is interpreted as timestamp data and imported into the timestamp field just fine.

However, when I use the API to do the same thing with the same file, I get this error:

"Illegal CSV schema type: TIMESTAMP"

More specifically, I'm using Google Apps Script to connect to the BigQuery API, but the response seems to be coming from the BigQuery API itself, which suggests this is not a feature of the API.

I know I can import as STRING, then convert to TIMESTAMP in my queries, but I was hoping to ultimately end up with a table schema with a timestamp field... populated from a CSV file... using the API... preferably through Apps Script for simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like TIMESTAMP is missing from the 'inline' schema parser. The fix should be in next week's build In the mean time, if you pass the schema via the 'schema' field rather than the schemaInline field it should work for you.

Comment: That is absolutely fantastic. Using the schema field was more lines of code, but it definitely did the trick. Thanks!